# How to copy Epichrome (SSB Chrome) apps to other workstations with active Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, rsync, google-chrome-extensions

[Epichrome](https://github.com/dmarmor/epichrome) is an absolutely great tool when it comes to site-specific-browsing.

I've found it's useful to be able to copy Epichrome apps to other systems, however it appears that Chrome itself must be having some gripes about copying Extensions and Themes (perhaps some kinds of signature issue?).

Here's the core logic I use for `rsync` in copying the Epichrome app itself on macOS from the `/Applications/` folder over to a new machine along with accompanying settings that live within `~/Library/Application Support/Epichrome/Apps`:

```
APP_PATH=${1}
DESTINATION=${2}
SSBProfilePath=`cat "${APP_PATH}/Contents/Resources/Scripts/config.sh" | grep SSBProfilePath | cut -d'=' -f2`
FULL_SSBProfilePath=$HOME/${SSBProfilePath}

exec_cmd "rsync -aE -e ssh '${APP_PATH}' $DESTINATION:/Applications/"
exec_cmd "rsync -aE -e ssh ${FULL_SSBProfilePath} '$DESTINATION:Library/Application\ Support/Epichrome/Apps/'"
```

What I'm finding is that when I open the SSB (Epichrome app) on the new system neither the previously active Theme nor previously active Extensions will show up.  What's more is that when I open the Epichrome Chrome's settings, it complains about some settings being reset and then I notice that the actual  `~/Library/Application\ Support/Epichrome/Apps/Default/Extensions`.

Any idea on how to make this work?  Is there a way to reset something such that Chrome will not be so picky or that it will re-sign or authorize Extensions?